# Running gem tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am breaking a monolithic Rails app into several gems. They all have a load of features that depend on the main application.

The purpose is to have a way to install the main application without all its features, but add certain features as gems if/when required.

None of these gems work without the main application or in a different application.

Each of the application components I am hoping to separate has a lot of specs including feature specs.

Before breaking the app apart I used to run all examples with:

```
bundle exec rspec
```

After separating features into gems it will only run the application specs, none of the gem specs.

How do I run these specs after installing the gems into the application?

Comment: The idea of a gem is that is a separated and testable piece of content. So the RSPEC tests that test the gem code, should be part of the gem. If the code isn't working on itself, I get the feeling that it shouldn't be separated in its own gem.

Comment: It has to be separated, sometimes I install the application only, without its additional features, and sometimes I install the whole thing. I can't include specs that fail, nor install the full application without all specs. If you just buy a car you don't need to have tests for the trailer. But if you have buy both car and trailer you need specs for both.

Comment: Echoing what @bo-oz said, for example look into Rails engines, the engine is a separate thing/gem/repository that does one useful thing say "allow any model to receive comments", the way the tests are structure is that engine repository includes a minimal Rails app so you can test your feature behaviour. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html

Comment: Another example you may look into is [aws-sdk-ruby](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/) they have a single repo with 140+ gems each have their own test and the CI runs all specs for all gems, maybe you can get some ideas from there. I've never looked into how `rspec` find the spec files but you could consider doing something like `bundle show my-gem` and using the output of this command add it to the list of paths rspec should include when testing.

Comment: Thank you very much Danilo and bo-oz I will look into this and rethink my approach.